# How can I trade fish/bugs between characters?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Something I did in the first Animal Crossing was make a house on an alternate character solely to showcase bugs/fish I felt were too cool to only leave in the museum. However bugs can't be mailed or dropped, so I'm at a loss as to how to do this.

Is there a way I can give bugs/fish to a second character or will that character have to find them themselves?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot place bugs/fish on the ground outside.  You cannot mail bugs/fish.  You cannot display bugs/fish in Re-Tail.  As far as I know, these are the only ways that you can transfer items betweens players.

So, based on this I would say that it is not possible to trade bugs/fish between players.

Comment: Yeah, after poking around there doesn't appear to be any way. As a sidenote, since I can display bugs/fish in the museum second floor I don't really need to trade fish to do what I wanted anyway.

Comment: Yeah the 2nd floor is great!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can trade between characters unfortunately. Each individual will have to catch each bug/fish respectively.

Comment: The same rule applies between games. You can't trade bugs/fish with visiting friends in towns and such.

Comment: Can you buy a bug or fish showcased in a StreetPass house?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mail fish or bugs, hence you can not buy it via streetpass because the item will be sent to you via mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't trade bugs, fish, and deep sea creatures. Your other character will have to catch it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can place fish, sharks, bugs or eaten assessed fossils. You can trade them like this and you can pick them back up. After what I did was made a museum in my house.